# "Memberify" or "membrify"?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes, neologisms

Which is the correct form when adding the *-ify* suffix to *member*?

1. memberify
2. membrify

I know it's not a regular word, I want to use it in a context for something like "make me a member".

Comment: Is this a word that you've seen, or one that you want to use? What does it mean?

Comment: Hi Barrie, I believe is not a reqular word, it just means something like "make me a member". I'm not a native English speaker so I do not know the rules very well, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Then it would be better to find some other way of expressing it, as in Christi's answer.

Comment: Where have you heard this word before? What does the dictionary say?

Comment: There is no such word, but if there would be it would be [memberize](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Memberized). There are several hundred hits for "memberized" on Google, as opposed to only a handful for either of your suggestions. And fewer than half seem to be eggcorns for "memorize". (Is this in the eggcorn database? If not, it should be.)

Comment: The word you want is "enrol".

Answer (score 1):

There is no word "memberify" in either form.   You may be looking for "initiate", "join" or "ratify" depending on context.  I suggest that the most common English construction similar to your question would probably be "I made him a member".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to coin a word, coin it. There is no "correct". (But be prepared for people to complain about your logogony).